# Refreshing only the updated row using ASP.NET MVC and jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I am new to ASP.NET MVC and jQuery and trying to do something classic. My need is to provide CRUD functionality with pop up edit form.

I have created a table and displaying data. I have a partial view rendering every single table row and the Index view is calling this in a loop:

```
<tbody>
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    @Html.Partial("_OrderRow", item)
}
</tbody>
```

Every row has an edit button, when i click it, a jQuery popup form is opening and it loads the edit form. When I click Update button, it performs the operation successfully(with an ajax request) and returns a JsonResult including the partial view (_OrderRow) rendered with the updated item:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult OrderEdit(OrderViewModel order)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            Order ord = OrderMapper.MapToEntity(order);

            db.Orders.Attach(ord);
            db.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(ord, EntityState.Modified);
            db.SaveChanges();

            return Json(new { Success = true, ObjectId = order.Id, Html = RenderPartialViewToString("_OrderRow", order) }, JsonRequestBehavior.DenyGet);
        }

        return Json(new { Success = false, Object = order }, JsonRequestBehavior.DenyGet);
    }
```

So in my updateSuccess function on the client side, I have the HTML of the updated item.

After that, I simply get the corresponding table row using jQuery and then replace it my up-to-date table row, using replaceWith.

This scenario works well so far. But my problem is that it doesn't change the actual HTML, it only manipulates the DOM. So if I use some table plug ins (like DataTables, TableSorter etc.) when I try to refresh the table(styling, paging etc.) they ignore my new table row. Because the actual HTML contains the old one.

It seems like I will face the same problem when I insert a new row or delete.

I prefer this way for not being dependent to any plug-in (as possible) and hold all the control over my views. So any help will really be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: The DOM is the browser's interpretation of the HTML in memory. Table plugins must operate on the DOM as well. Have you seen the plugin fail? If you have a question about a specific plugin, that might help guide the discussion.

Comment: Why not replace the whole table instead of one row? Is there any reason you can't do that? I would put that whole table into its own partial view...unless there's some specific reason your not.

Comment: @Mike : For example, jQuery DataTables plug-in, when I refresh the updated field like i have said before, it loses its styling etc. since it's a new <tr>. So I call the fnDraw() function to refresh the table. I expect that it re-styles the entire table including my new <tr> too. But it renders the old one (with the old values) because the actual HTML (when I view the source of the page) does not change.

Comment: I may not be clear, so you can understand my issue following these steps : 1 . Create a table with some <tr>s. 2. Style it with jQuery DataTables plugin (not server side)  3. Replace one of the <tr>s with a new one (change some values in it) using jQuery's replaceWith function. You'll see it loses its styling, sorting, etc. 4. Call its fnDraw() function refresh these. You'll see the old values come back.

Comment: @AwDogsGo2Heaven : The reason I replace only the row which is updated is that I dont want to reload the entire data. I also don't want to lose any sorting or filtering.

Comment: Aw, I see what the problem is, at least with DataTables. That plugin has its own API for adding rows (`fnAddData`). The reason `fnDraw()` removes the row is that the plugin keeps its own internal copy of the DOM and renders that when the method is called. Looks like there are functions which can take external data (`fnAddTr`). I expect other table plugins have similar APIs you'll need to call if you're adding your own rows.